# I'm trying to set up Ubuntu to serve as an IDE for C development

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, emacs, clang

I don't really know how to phrase it, but I am not looking to use an actual IDe (codeblocks, netbeans, eclipse, etc).

I have tried to follow several different tutorials, but things keep getting screwed up along the way and nothing ever quite fits as it is supposed to.

https://earthserver.com/Setting_up_a_C%2B%2B11_development_environment_on_Linux_with_Clang_and_Emacs

The above link is essentially what I want to do, but there is next to no trouble-shooting for when something goes wrong.

Can someone please point me in a dummy proof direction so I can get started?

I am willing to learn but am not getting anywhere after nearly two weeks of hitting road blocks.

I am currently running Ubuntu 13.10 64bit.

Comment: If you have tried several sets of instructions and nothing is working, you might have a borked ubuntu installation.

Comment: All you need is ubuntu, GCC (GDB included), SSH and netbeans (remote development).  If i were you, i'd get to know these items in that order respectively

Comment: OP, this is primarily an installation question not a programming issue.  SuperUser or AskUbuntu would be the more appropriate sites for this and you should ask one question per issue as you encounter them.  It's pretty hard to unravel 20 steps you might have undertaken and then figure out why the outcome is borked.

Comment: You don't need an IDE to develop in C or C++. Use `emacs` and compile with `gcc -Wall -g` (for C code) or `g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11` for (C++11 code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [guide](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html) explains how to setup CEDET for name completion & code navigation.

Description of debugger integration is in the standard [GNU Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/GDB-Graphical-Interface.html) (or `C-h i d m Emacs RET m gdb TAB RET`